# How do I dynamically change the text color of a theme?

Tags: android, themes

I would like the change the text color of all TextViews once the user chooses a different font color.

I can achieve this by linking all associated TextViews and call setTextColor on them.

But I would like to know if this could also be done through customizing Themes?

Comment: AFAIK No. The way you mentioned is the way to go.

Comment: That's pretty saddening, considering the amount of TVs one might have...

Comment: Use an ArrayList or something similar to link all those TVs, it's not that bad.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question,
but nevertheless,
I seem to have an answer.

In its simplest form.

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="InvertedTheme" parent="BaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

In your androidmanifest set;

```
<activity
  android:name=".SomeActivity"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/BaseTheme" />
```

Then in your SomeActivity.java;

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

  static final String INVERTED_EXTRA = "inverted";

  private void invertTheme() {
    // to make the theme take effect we need to restart the activity
    Intent inverted = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
    inverted.putExtra(INVERTED_EXTRA, true);
    startActivity(inverted);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // must be before the setContentView
    if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra(INVERTED_EXTRA, false))
      setTheme(R.style.InvertedTheme);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);
    ...
```

I tried without starting a new activity,
but it doesn't reset the colors.